# What does React turn my text into lots of <span>'s?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a string that I am displaying using React/JSX. I am using version `0.14.7` Here is the String

```
renderValue(bus) {
    let busDisplay = `(${bus.busIdCode })`;
    return (
            <span>{`${bus.country} ${busDisplay}`}</span>
    )
}
```

When I look in the dom, all of the text is broken apart into separate `<span />`'s, even the parenthesis.  Here is the result:

```
<div>
  <div>
  <span>
    <span>
      <span>Aruba</span>
      <span> (</span>
      <span>ABW001</span>
      <span>)</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

How can I make all the text a single `<span />` and get rid of this pollution in the dom?

Comment: What version of React? This fiddle, using react 15, does not create spans https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/65062/ Also does this actually affect your application?

Comment: There is nothing between the code above and the rendering of the `html`.

Comment: Check the Major Changes section on the Release Note of React v15 specifically this "No more extra <span>s" https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v15.0.0 So as others suggested, you might want to update your React to version 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problems here, that's probably just how React used to render text nodes. It doesn't matter at all, it's just a disposable DOM render artifact. Current versions of React appear to render text in a different way.

If you want to avoid additional spans, use the current version of React. You're currently 15 major releases behind.